# Unable to implement fmt::Display for a struct with a generic type

Tags: generics, struct, rust

I have a struct Character which takes in a generic type T. I am unable to figure out how to implement the fmt::Display trait for Character. This is what I tried:

```
pub struct Character<T> {
    pub name: String,
    pub level: u32,
    pub class: T,
    pub attack: i32,
    pub defense: i32,
    pub speed: i32,
}

impl fmt::Display for Character<T> {
    // Display trait for Player
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "[{}] {} (Lv {})", self.class, self.name, self.level)
    }
}
```

The error states that T cannot be found in the scope in the line `impl fmt::Display for Character<T>`

I've tried searching for how you would do this, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: To summarize the reason and solution: Just because the object itself (`Character<T>`) should implement `Display`, it doesn't mean that the `T` does too, so if you only make `Character<T> where T: Display` implement `Display, you have no error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
use std::fmt;

impl<T> fmt::Display for Character<T>
where
    T: fmt::Display,
{
    // Display trait for Player
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "[{}] {} (Lv {})", self.class, self.name, self.level)
    }
}
```

- `impl<T>` states that the following is an implementation for something generic (just as `Character`)
- `where T: std::fmt::Display` requires that `T` implements `Display`. This is needed because you want to `write` `self.class`, which is of type `T`